# How to check validity of phone number in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have written the following query to print all the rows where phone number is not of 10 digits or if it contains any alphabets but it is not working. Can someone tell me why it is not working

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Phone_number NOT LIKE '[0-9]*10';
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (I doubt the answer will be same for these two.)

Comment: I'm using Oracle

Comment: try using REGEXP_LIKE

Comment: Why aren't you storing phone-numbers normalized in E.164 format? That would render this query, and your task, moot.

Comment: NANP ("10-digit") phone numbers have more stringent validation rules than just "every character is a digit", for example the 3-digit area code cannot start with a `1`. If you *really* want to validate your database you should do it in application-code using `libphonenumber` or similar because PL/SQL simply lacks the capability to validate phone numbers correctly and thoroughly.

Comment: I agree with @Dai - either use libphnone number as Java stored procedure or move the whole logic into application and do perform this check on application side.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in consideration that phone numbers have more complex rules, you could use something like this.

I show different premises that you can get a better idea:

Data Demo

```
SQL> create table test_phone ( phone_number varchar2(20) ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into test_phone values ( '4429239220' ); -- 10 digits

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test_phone values ( '10229383890' ); -- 11 digits 

1 row created.

SQL>  insert into test_phone values ( 'GE4914098998833' ); -- contains letters

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test_phone values ( 'AGCD292911' ); -- 10 digits but letters

 1 row created.
```

Premise: 10 digits only

```
SQL> select * from test_phone where regexp_like(phone_number,'^[[:digit:]]{10}$') ;

PHONE_NUMBER
--------------------
4429239220
```

Premise ( 10 digits or any with letters )

```
SQL>  select * from test_phone where regexp_like(phone_number,'^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{10}*$');

PHONE_NUMBER
--------------------
4429239220
AGCD292911
```

Premise not ( 10 digits or letters )

```
SQL>  select * from test_phone where not regexp_like(phone_number,'^[a-zA-Z0-9-]{10}*$');

PHONE_NUMBER
--------------------
10229383890
GE4914098998833
```

Premise: only those records that are not 10 digits neither contains any alphabet letter. Can be achieve without regular expressions

```
SQL> select * from test_phone where lengthc(phone_number) != 10 and validate_conversion(phone_number as number)=1
  2  ;

PHONE_NUMBER
--------------------
10229383890
```

Comment: @Sarah, any feedback?

Answer (score -3):

I got it using `NOT REGEXP`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    Phone_number NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: It worked in the W3 schools editor but it is not working in Oracle

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't support regular expression in (standard) SQL and Oracle. Another good example why you shouldn't rely on information from w3fools

Comment: In Oracle, `LIKE` uses wildcards, which are not the same thing as regular expressions. Also, instead of repeating regex `[0-9]` 10 times, you can use `[0-9]{10}`. This still isn't a perfect validation check though, for example it would match `'banana1234567890'`.